# where can I find log files in devstack?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, devstack, openstack-neutron, openstack-horizon

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=pass123
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
HOST_IP=192.168.1.57

# Services
ENABLED_SERVICES=rabbit,mysql,key
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,n-api,n-crt,n-obj,n-cpu,n-cond,n-sch,n-novnc,n-cauth
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,s-proxy,s-object,s-container,s-account
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,g-api,g-reg
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,cinder,c-api,c-vol,c-sch,c-bak
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,trove,tr-api,tr-tmgr,tr-cond
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,horizon

# Ceilometer
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,ceilometer-acompute,ceilometer-acentral,ceilometer-collector,ceilometer-api
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,ceilometer-alarm-notify,ceilometer-alarm-eval

# Heat
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,heat,h-api,h-api-cfn,h-api-cw,h-eng BLED_SERVICES+=,g-api,g-reg
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,cinder,c-api,c-vol,c-sch,c-bak
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,trove,tr-api,tr-tmgr,tr-cond
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,horizon

# Ceilometer
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,ceilometer-acompute,ceilometer-acentral,ceilometer-collector,ceilometer-api
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,ceilometer-alarm-notify,ceilometer-alarm-eval

# Heat
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,heat,h-api,h-api-cfn,h-api-cw,h-eng

# Neutron
DISABLED_SERVICES=n-net
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,q-svc,q-agt,q-dhcp,q-l3,q-meta,q-metering,neutron

# Neutron - Load Balancing
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,q-lbaas

# VLAN configuration
Q_PLUGIN=ml2
ENABLE_TENANT_VLANS=True

# GRE tunnel configuration
Q_PLUGIN=ml2
ENABLE_TENANT_TUNNELS=True
Q_ML2_TENANT_NETWORK_TYPE=gre

# Logging
LOGFILE=$DEST/logs/stack.sh.log
SCREEN_LOGDIR=$DEST/logs/screen
LOGDAYS=2

# Swift
SWIFT_HASH=66a3d6b56c1f479c8b4e70ab5c2000f5
SWIFT_REPLICAS=1
SWIFT_DATA_DIR=$DEST/data

# Neutron
DISABLED_SERVICES=n-net
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,q-svc,q-agt,q-dhcp,q-l3,q-meta,q-metering,neutron

# Neutron - Load Balancing
ENABLED_SERVICES+=,q-lbaas

# VLAN configuration
Q_PLUGIN=ml2
ENABLE_TENANT_VLANS=True

# GRE tunnel configuration
Q_PLUGIN=ml2
ENABLE_TENANT_TUNNELS=True
Q_ML2_TENANT_NETWORK_TYPE=gre

# Logging
LOGFILE=$DEST/logs/stack.sh.log
SCREEN_LOGDIR=$DEST/logs/screen
LOGDAYS=2

# Swift
SWIFT_HASH=66a3d6b56c1f479c8b4e70ab5c2000f5
SWIFT_REPLICAS=1
SWIFT_DATA_DIR=$DEST/data

# Tempest
enable_service tempest
```

This in my local.conf file. I installed devstack using this configuration.
I'm new to devstack and I can't find the logs now. I've searched the internet and can't find a clear path to the log files. I need the log files to solve an error that says no hosts were found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [this link](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/systemd.html) devstack now runs all services as `systemd` unit files (I can't recall exactly since which version, although I would say since the `pike` release)

Thus, to check the logs of the different services you can use the `journalctl` utility (along with its infinite options).

Some examples:

```
sudo journalctl -f -u devstack@n-cond.service
```

In order to check the `nova-conductor` logs.

Or:

```
sudo journalctl -f -u devstack@h*
```

to check all heat-related services.

Answer (score 1):

In `devstack`, logs of `openstack` services are attached with linux screens. you can find them by running the command `screen -x stack`. And you can switch to each service log.

Troubleshooting the error "**No valid hosts were found**":

1. Check whether there are enough resources like vcpu, disk, RAM in the tenant/project.
2. If you are using `availability_zone` then check for available resources for the compute host in that zone.

Comment: Output *****Screen -x stack**** There is no screen to be attached matching stack.
 Plenty of resources are available in compute node but still unable to launch instance.